# Accessing one class member in another class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class A
{
 public:
    int m_count;
    int m_values[300];
    void Method1();
}
class B
{
    void Method2();
}

void A::Method1()
{
    for(int i=0; i<m_count; i++)
    {
        creates instances of class B
    }
}
```

B::Method2() needs m_values array of class A for each instances of class B. Here m_values get update every minute by another function in class A.
Is it possible to access m_values of class A in all instances of class B?

Comment: `m_values` of which instance of class `A`?

Comment: class A has only one instance

Comment: Please fill in the types of `m_count` and `m_values`.

Comment: And add the private/public qualifiers.

Comment: @Ramesh then why can't you access that field? Because it's private? Because you don't know the address of that instance? What have you tried so far?

Comment: please post real code / [mcve] and the compiler error. Introducing additional errors in what you post here just makes it harder to understand the question.

Comment: "_B::Method2() needs m_values array of class A for each instances of class B_" - but which instance of `A` does it need to access? Edit: Now that you've made the member variables in `A` `public` any other class may access the members. So why not `B`?

Comment: There are no inheritance relations between classes A and B, the fact that the instances of B are created by an instance of A is irrelevant.

In the current code, the members of A are public, so anyone can access them. If you want a "safer" implementation, you can make the array private and make B a friend. If you need B to access the specific A that created it, you need to keep a explicit link from B to A.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
private:
    Type m_values[300];
public:
    Type getValue(int index) { return m_values[index]; }
};

class B {
private:
    A &a;
public:
    void Method2() { /* can call a.getValue(<number>); */ }
    B b(A &a) : a(a) {}
};

void A::Method1()
{
    for(int i=0; i<m_count; i++) {
        creates instances of class B
        B b(*this);
    }
}
```